# Eclipse only finding jars in local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm new with Maven so don't kill me if this stupid question or if I'm not using the right terminology describing my problem, please.

From what I understand Maven fetches `jar` files from the Internet. I'm trying to add dependencies through Maven of Spring framework `jar`s like beans, context, logging, core, etc.

[image: Trying to add dependencies but only these jars show up]

But the issue is only `jar`s that I have downloaded before show up in the search like the ones shown.

I've looked at other threads that tell me to rebuild and update index through *Window* > *Show View* > *Other* > *type Maven in filter* and *select Maven Repositories* > *Right-click on central* and *Update Index*.
Or auto-update Maven repositories when restarting Eclipse but both haven't worked.

I'm not sure how I got Maven to search the remote repository in the first place but I want to be able to do that again and not search through what seems be a local group of `jar`s.

Comment: What you're using is an interface in eclipse to the pom.xml file, which you can also edit by hand. (I, personally, didn't even know of that fancy wizard).
I'm guessing that does work.

Moreover, if you're making a spring project, have you checked http://start.spring.io , which lets you download a complete maven setup with all the necessary dependencies?

Comment: The groupId of all artifacts released by the Spring project is [`org.springframework`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/), not `spring`. And I wouldn't use this interface to add your dependencies... prefer the simple way of finding the correct coordinates [from the documentation](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/).

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: You rollbacked my edit. Why? Maven runs perfectly fine. Your question is about an Eclipse search wizard, not about Maven. It's eclipse that doesn't suggest artifacts in its serach wizard. Maven has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Oh I assumed my problem was part of maven, not a eclipse search interface/wizard and thought I made the mistake of putting 'Eclipse' in title, unaware someone edited it.

https://66.media.tumblr.com/d53c3ad64745c5403426036d2f5bb86d/tumblr_o9qyovENsS1ryea2vo1_1280.png  
  
Anyways, I remember that when I did a search through that, it displayed other version such 4.2, 4.1 etc  for all the org.springframework jars a week ago - but now if I try to search for spring jars - it only displays ones I have downloaded.

Edit: Not behind a proxy

Answer (score 1):

by default Maven (if not in offline mode) will firstly try to locate the artifact on your local repository (.m2), if not able to find, it will try to locate it on Maven Central or in the other repositories configured on your maven user settings or project pom.xml.

To ensure that Maven is not being able to communicate with remote repositories, you may access the properly view (Window > Show View > Maven Repositories).

[image: Maven Repositories]

Ref: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Ref: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html

In case of doubt, please reply a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I've tried rebuilding the index like so since it was mentioned in many other threads and it doesn't work. I've checked the settings xml in .m2 to check it wasn't in offline mod too. Sorry if figuring all this out is a hassle, I guess I can make do for now with the local repository. Thanks again, I'd leave an upvote if I could.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it. I didn't even manage to figure out the exact problem but I deleted eclipse and all its plugins, reinstalled them and switched work space directories and created my projects from a new and that seemed to fix and I can finally reach the central repository.